# Help me with this logic (newbie)

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a half pyramid number series with the entered starting number and the number of lines in a html page using Javascript and show the result in html page . I have done the Java scripting and stuff . What I don't get is the logic to it.

Take a look at this you may get an idea what I'm talking about:
[image]

Here is my function in Javascript that will be triggered on a button click function

```
doFunction(){
 var enteredNumber=document.getElementById("start");
 var lines=document.getElementById("lines");
 var result;
 for(i=0;i<=lines.value;i++) {
 for(j=enteredNumber.value;j<=i;j++) { document.write(j + "&nbsp;" + "&nbsp;"); } 
 document.write("<br />");
 }
}
```

Help me with the logic to print following order:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

There is a condition. I will specify `$start` and `$lines`.

If `$start = 5` and `$lines = 3` then output should be like:

```
5
5 6
5 6 7
```

I have had used the for loop , but that doesn't work if I give my own start number that is higher than the number of lines.

I actually need it done with Javascript, I have had done the necessary but I'm confused with the logic to generate such series (with the user given values) I had actually used two for loops to generate the regular number series like below `1 1 2 1 2 3` and so on.

Comment: I actually need it done with Javascript , I have had done the necessary but I'm confused with the logic to generate such series ( with the user given values ) 

I had actually used two for loops to generate the regular number series like below 

1
1 2
1 2 3 
and so on..

Comment: So you want it done it JavaScript, tags the question as C, and your variables look like PHP. Though could you please edit and explain your question better, because I don't seem to understand it.

Comment: you should post the code you have as well

Comment: Sorry if that was mis leading , as I said I'm new to programing . Please bare with me . 


Actually I need to generate a half pyramid number series with the entered starting number and the number of lines in a html page using Javascript and show the result in html page . I have done the Java scripting and stuff . What I don't get is the logic to it  . Take a look at this you may get an idea what I'm talking about http://imgur.com/cVfw1xD

Comment: Here is my function in Javascript that will be triggered on a button click

function doFunction(){
     var enteredNumber=document.getElementById("start");
                
      var lines=document.getElementById("lines");
                
        var result;
                for(i=0;i<=lines.value;i++)
                {
                    for(j=enteredNumber.value;j<=i;j++)
                    {    
                        document.write(j + "&nbsp;" + "&nbsp;");
                      
                    }
                    document.write("<br />");   
                }}

Comment: I have done it , someone close this question . Thanks for the responses and edits .

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question by yourself, write it in the form of an answer and accept if. Else, accept the answer that was most useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use separate variables for storing the number of lines, the number you're starting with.
Algorithm should look like this:

```
$lines = input
$start = input
for($i = 0;$i<$lines;$i++){
    $psudo_start=$start;
    for($j = 0;$j<$i;$j++){
        print $psudo_start;
        $psudo_start++;
    }
    print newline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need default values for your start/lines in case none were provided, then you grab the input and check to see if you should use that or the defaults. Remember your input is a string so you need to use `parseInt()` to convert it to a numeric.

```
// If no start value is provided default to a start of 1
var startVal = 1;
var enteredStart = document.getElementById("start").value.trim();
if (enteredStart.length > 0) {
    startVal = parseInt(enteredStart);
}

// if no lines value is provided default to a lines of 5
var linesVal = 5;
var enteredLines = document.getElementById("lines").value.trim();
if (enteredLines.length > 0) {
    linesVal = parseInt(enteredLines);
}
```

Now you have your start and lines, either those the user set or the defaults. Build your output string:

```
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    for (var j = startVal; j <= startVal + i; j++) {
        output += j + "  ";
    }
    output += "</br>";
}
```

Note that your inner loop should be going as long as `j <= startVal + i` to solve your problem with not printing when start number is higher than number of lines.

Instead of doing `document.write()` it would be better to have a div in your page and changing the text in that div to display your output.

```
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = output;
```